# Windows 7 NON-Boot 6TB array results in a limited, 2048GB "disk"

Tags: windows-7, raid, gpt

I have Windows 7 using an LSI 3Ware 9650SE-8LPML with 4 of the WD Green 2TB drives. I've done a bunch of reading on this; I'm not using it as a boot, and the array has no data; it can be deleted and recreated any way necessary.

When i make the raid 5 array in the 3ware bios, the resulting 5.6-ishTB of space is correct. Upon entering diskpart.exe OR windows storage "disk management", the un-initialized disk shows only 2048GB of space.

Doesn't matter if I pick MBR (wrong) or GPT (which is what it should be), the resulting disk is 2048GB and cannot be formatted any larger.

What am I missing? Is this possible to have all 5.6ish TB as a single, add-on drive letter for storage? (not booting!)

Comment: Check for an updated driver for the HBA.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 7 support ensure you have the latest code set (9.5.3) and firmware (v4.10.00.021 April 2011) from LSI.

> Highlights for Release 9.5.3:
>
> - This release provides support for VMware 4.0.
> - This release provides support for Mac OS X Snow Leopard.
> - This release provides support for Microsoft Windows 7.

You can [get them via his link](http://www.lsi.com/channel/products/raid_controllers/3ware_9650se-8lpml/index.html).